# I'm trying to use the JScrollPane component in Java

Tags: jscrollpane

Hi guys i would like you to help me display parallel arrays on a JScrollPane. The arrays are of String and double data types. Here is my sample code: String[] items = {"fish","frog"};                                                                            double[] prices = {12,19}; I'm supposed to put them on the JScrollPane, with the element in position 0 of the items array next to the prices position 0 and so on;

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you can't put your data in `JTable` and add the table to the scroll pane?

```
import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument;
import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

class ItemTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    final String[] items;

    final double[] prices;

    public ItemTableModel(String[] items, double[] prices) {
        checkNotNull(items);
        checkNotNull(prices);
        checkArgument(items.length == prices.length);
        this.items = items;
        this.prices = prices;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return items.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            return items[rowIndex];
        case 1:
            return prices[rowIndex];
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            return String.class;
        case 1:
            return Object.class;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }

    @Override
     public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            return "Item";
        case 1:
            return "Price";
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }       
    }
}

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable createAndShowGui = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }

        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(createAndShowGui);
    }


    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        String[] items = { "fish", "frog" };
        double[] prices = { 12, 19 };       
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        ItemTableModel tableModel = new ItemTableModel(items, prices);
        JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
        //table.setTableHeader(null); // uncomment  to hide the table header
        frame.setContentPane(new JScrollPane(table));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }   
}
```